# Converting dictionary of dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that looks like this..

```
{1:[{"pid_name":"process_A", "data":{"data_1":1234, "data_2":2345}}, {...}, {...}],
2:[...],
3:[...]
}
```

so key for each row is an index, and each row has an array (dynamic length). Each object in the array does have the same schema, pid_name, and data. And data has two data points.
Ultimately I want my data to be some kind of time series of two data frames, one for data_point 1 and data_point 2, y-axis being the pid_name, x-axis being the index

I've gotten to the point where I managed to have x-axis being the index, using

```
df = pd.DataFrame({key: pd.Series(value) for key, value in df.items()})
```

and filled in values using NaN if the particular process is missing.

The issue is that the length of the array is not always the same (but has the max length), and the order of item in the array isn't fixed.

I appreciate any help on getting somewhere with this data.

edit:
expected output to look like

```
table for data_1

         |  1  |  2  |
process_A|1234 | 212 
process_B|1111 | 222
process_C|23   | 456
process_D|NaN  | 789

the same goes for table for data_2
```

sample input:

```
{1:[{"pid_name":"process_A", "data":{"data_1":1234, "data_2":...}}, {"pid_name":"process_B", "data":{"data_1":1111, "data_2":...}}, {"pid_name":"process_C", "data":{"data_1":23, "data_2":...}}],
2:[{"pid_name":"process_A", "data":{"data_1":212, "data_2":...}}, {"pid_name":"process_B", "data":{"data_1":222, "data_2":...}}, {"pid_name":"process_C", "data":{"data_1":456, "data_2":...}},
{"pid_name":"process_D", "data":{"data_1":789, "data_2":...}}],
3:[{},{},...]
}
```

the whole point is to make a multiple line graph (like a time series data), interval being the x-axis and the data_1 and data_2 to be some number on y_axis so it can be on two different tables.

Comment: Could you please provide a desired output based on some input data we can use as sample to test our solution before sharing it with you? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a expected output (even one row), so that people can exactly understand what you want. It seems that you want to make one dataframe considst of three columns: pid_name, data_1, data_2, but I am not sure becuase you mentioned 'two data frames'.

Comment: @CeliusStingher and Sangkeun Park added some input and output. And yes, it can be two different data frames!

Comment: The units for data_1 and data_2 are different anyways so they should be on the different data frames - it's just the way the data came in. I'm trying to break it down so I can draw some plots trending over interval.

Comment: @am1212 why the value of 789 is assigned to second column, not to first column?

Comment: it's assigned to the second column because the 789 belongs to the interval 2 (the key in the dictionary) and process_D does not exist in interval 1.

Comment: the sample output only contains the information of  data_1. Sorry if it's really unclear :/ Actually, I'm not sure if the desired sample output is the best for the time series data, each line representing each process.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look and try to come up with an answer shortly.